# How can I get and handle a return codes in a C program if sftp fails to put the file in a sftp server?

Tags: c, ftp, return, sftp

How can we get and handle the sftp return codes in a C program if sftp fails to put the file in a server?

We need to transfer the files again if sftp fails to put it in the sftp server.

Comment: Are you calling a library function? using a command line tool?  more information is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to use the command line sftp from within a C program, this program illustrates one way to do it (it's rather ugly but shows the idea):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ret;
    ret = system(argv[1]);
    if (ret == -1) {
        printf("Error in system!");
        /* *** */
        exit(-1);
    }
    ret = (signed char)WEXITSTATUS(ret);
    printf("%d\n", ret);
    return 0;
}
```

Use `man system`, and then `man 2 wait` for info on WEXITSTATUS macro.

The value of *ret* is the return code of sftp and can be used to determine failure in sftp and decide what to do next.